# My function resets values when repeated. Is there a way to solve this?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I am creating a small game to test out some of the skills I learned in some tutorials.

I created this function:

```py
def attack(strength, weapon_damage, attack_modifier, health):
    damage_to_enemy = strength * weapon_damage * randint(2, 5) * attack_modifier
    print(f"You did {damage_to_enemy} damage to the enemy")
    health = health - damage_to_enemy
    print(health)
```

I call this function when my character or an enemy attacks like this:

```py
attack(
    character_stats_dictionary["strength"],
    character_stats_dictionary["weapon damage"],
    character_stats_dictionary["attack modifier"],
    enemy_1_stats_dictionary["enemy_health_1"],
)
```

Unfortunately, it resets the health stat every time it was executed. It didn't used to do this before it was a function. This is the old code that worked:

```py
damage_to_enemy = (
    character_stats_dictionary["strength"]
    * character_stats_dictionary["weapon damage"]
    * randint(2, 5)
    * character_stats_dictionary["attack modifier"]
)
print(f"You did {damage_to_enemy} damage to the enemy")

enemy_1_stats_dictionary["enemy_health_1"] = (
    enemy_1_stats_dictionary["enemy_health_1"] - damage_to_enemy
)
print(enemy_1_stats_dictionary["enemy_health_1"])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't modify the values inside, unless it's part of a Python object. For a quantity like an `int` or `float`, you'll just be modifying a local copy.

Comment: I would recommend just passing in the dictionary. You probably can modify the dictionary's contents within a function.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your operation, so that the dictionary is being used directly, and is modified within the function so the values are retained.

```py
def attack(enemy):
    strength = enemy["strength"]
    weapon_damage = enemy["weapon damage"]
    attack_modifier = enemy["attack modifier"]
    health = enemy["enemy_health_1"]
    damage_to_enemy = strength * weapon_damage * randint(2, 5) * attack_modifier
    print(f"You did {damage_to_enemy} damage to the enemy")
    enemy.update(health=(health - damage_to_enemy))
    print(health)
```

Which is called this way:

```py
attack(character_stats_dictionary)
```